# Made us fool VS Made fool of us

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which one of the following is correct sentence.

1. He made a fool of us.
2. He made us fool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is *make a fool of somebody*.

In theory you can also say *make somebody a fool*, (and hence *He made us fools*) but I can't think of a context in which I would say that.

Comment: You could have "*He made us **look like** fools*". What about "*He made us fools [in his game]*"? (although doesn't stand on its own)

Comment: @Smock: Yes. I decided not to mention _look like fools_, as I thought it just complicated matters.